# Display of checkboxes in dataTable in Shiny not displaying, html code displays, how to fix that?

Tags: r, checkbox, datatables, shiny

I am displaying a dataTable in Shiny, and I added the checkboxes to one of my dataTables, however it doesn't display the checkboxes but shows the code the html code for the checkbox "  "  Does anyone know the fix for this? Thank you!

Here is a summary of code I used:

Ui file:

```
DT::dataTableOutput(paste0("siFactors_",i))

Server file:
output[[paste0('siFactors_', i)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
                datatable(final_array,
                   extensions='KeyTable',
                    rownames = checkboxRows(final_array, checked = box_indices),
                               options = list(deferRender = TRUE,
                                               paging = FALSE,
                                              searching = FALSE,
                                            autoWidth = FALSE,
                                                scrollX = TRUE,
                                                scrollY = 600,
                                                scrollCollapse = TRUE                                       
                                )
                  )
      })
```

Comment: checkboxRows() has been removed from DT, and you probably don't need the checkboxes any more: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

Comment: How would you recommend then by selecting the rows on the server side i.e. if I were to launch an app, then it would already have rows selected.

Comment: For the record, same question answered in the shiny-discuss mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/KZxcfN6pznM/wydUqRaQ-0AJ Please feel free to paste it here and accept it if it works for you.